# Is there a way to retrieve region information using golang azure blob storage sdk?

Tags: azure, go, azure-blob-storage

Is there any API or other way to get container region information for azure blob storage in golang?
We have service, container URL.

Answer (score 1):

There is REST API  for Azure Storage Account.

As  the blob containers region is same as the Storage Account region, you can use the Azure Storage REST API to fetch the region of the blob    storage.

You can use below API call to fetch the storage  account properties :

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}?api-version=2021-04-01
```

If you want a specific property of a Storage Account like location, you can use expand property :

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}?api-version=2021-04-01&$expand={$expand}
```

**Reference** :
[Storage Accounts - Get Properties - REST API (Azure Storage Resource Provider) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/get-properties)

**Golang REST API reference** :
[Golang REST API - Getting Started - GoLang Docs](https://golangdocs.com/golang-rest-api)

Comment: Is there any way to get location, if we do not have subscription id? We only have storage account name and account key.